# How to detect keyboard input in languages ​other than English in Operator modal via Python

Tags: python, scripting

When the user uses keyboard languages ​​such as Chinese and Japanese, how to catch the text input in operator modal?

```
import bpy

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC': return {'CANCELLED'}

        print(event.ascii, event.unicode)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Blender's Python API may not provide direct access to IME input events